# Docker + Celery tells me not to run as root, but once I don't, I lack permissions to run

Tags: python, django, docker, permissions, celery

I have a Django (2.1.2) Docker project that I try to include Celery (4.2.1) which will exit 0 in the end due to permission errors.

docker-compose.yml

```
...
celery:
  build: .
  command: celery worker -A core --workdir /opt/services/web_app/src -l info
  volumes:
    - .:/opt/services/web_app/src
  depends_on:
    - database1
    - redis
```

After i build with 'docker-compose build' and then run 'docker-compose up' I get this error message:

```
celery_1  | /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/platforms.py:796:
celery_1  | RuntimeWarning: You're running the worker with superuser privileges: this 
celery_1  | is absolutely not recommended!
celery_1  |
celery_1  | Please specify a different user using the --uid option
```

So.. I didn't even know Docker had "users" so I added this to my 'Dockerfile' at the bottom before expose.

```
...
RUN groupadd -g 999 celery && \
    useradd -r -u 999 -g celery celery
USER celery

EXPOSE 8000
```

and then updated the 'Dockerfile' with the user:

```
...
celery:
  build: .
  command: celery worker -A core --workdir /opt/services/web_app/src -l info --uid=celery
  volumes:
    - .:/opt/services/web_app/src
  depends_on:
    - database1
    - redis
```

and when I run it now I get error message:

```
celery_1  | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/platforms.py", line 502,
celery_1  | in initgroups return os.initgroups(username, gid)
celery_1  | PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

Answer (score 4):

Change your Dockerfile:

```
WORKDIR /app
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash celery
COPY . /app
RUN chown -R celery:celery /app
USER celery
```

And set `C_FORCE_ROOT=false`

Or, you can force container to run as non-user:

```
docker run --user 1000 -v /root/secrets.txt:/tmp/secrets.txt <img>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. If you want to specify a `uid`, you use the `multi` command, not `worker`, and you run the `multi` command as root.  If you want to use `worker` just run the command without `uid`.
2. You can also just set the C_FORCE_ROOT env variable to `1` and run this as root in docker if this is just for local development.

n.b., you may also need to update file permissions in case your celery task writes anything to the filesystem (like log files, or temp files).

Comment: "and run this as root in docker if this is just for local development" it is very normal to run as root in Docker _in production_!